# Can it really more optimal to fetch 16 bytes as data with a single instruction than to do four immediate stores of 4 bytes each?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, cpu-architecture, micro-optimization

Consider this C code and the generated (by GCC) assembler code for it:

```
 + cat x.c
 1  struct S
 2  {
 3    int a, b, c, d, e;
 4  };

 5  void foo(struct S *s)
 6  {
 7    s->a = 1;
 8    s->b = 2;
 9    s->c = 3;
10    s->d = 4;
11    s->e = 5;
12  }
```

build with: `gcc -O3 -S x.c`.  (Output trimmed of some assembler directives)

```
+ cat x.s
18  foo:
21      movdqa  .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
22      movl    $5, 16(%rdi)
23      movups  %xmm0, (%rdi)
24      ret

28      .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
29      .align 16
30  .LC0:
31      .long   1
32      .long   2
33      .long   3
34      .long   4
35      .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)"
```

At line 21, a single instruction loads the 16 bytes containing the values for fields `a` through `d` as data.

It seems unintuitive to me that typical performance would be better than doing four immediate store instructions.  Wouldn't a stall on a (data) cache load be more likely?

(I believe that clang/LLVM also optimizes for x86 in this manner.)

Comment: It depends on the surrounding code which choice will be better.  And on D-cache vs. I-cache pressure.  Remember that using fewer uops lets out-of-order exec start looking at what's next sooner, and the load address has no data dependency on anything so *it* can get started as soon as OoO exec sees it ahead of other work.  Depending on how quickly there's a reload, it might be fine to wait for the movdqa to come from L3 or L2 cache.  If this runs often, the data is probably hot in some cache.  If it doesn't, then its performance doesn't matter and saving code-size is nice.